# How to register your token in the user wallet

Tags: web3js, metamask, wallets

I have created a token. How can I make it my token appear inside the user wallet and the wallet to show the token balance?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The user token balance is an important for the token vendor and the user. However due to open and decentralised nature of the blockchain, wallets do not show tokens by default.

- Modern Ethereum wallets support [EIP-747](https://github.com/estebanmino/EIPs/blob/master/EIPS/eip-747.md) standard that allow your dApp to register a token through user interaction (button press on a website)
- Some wallets have an in-house whitelist or Github repository, where you need to submit your token details
- Some wallets offer only the option for the user to manually type contract address, token name, symbol and decimal amount

[A good tutorial from MetaMask how to make a web3.js interfacetion for registering a token](https://docs.metamask.io/guide/registering-your-token.html#code-free-example)

Answer (score 2):

In addition, there are some curated lists of tokens that you can submit your token to. Applications, such as wallets, pull tokens from these curated lists.

1. **Token Curated List of Tokens** https://tokens.kleros.io
   (https://uniswap.ninja/ pulls token list from here, for example. This one is a decentralized list, meaning everyone maintains it, not just a curator.)
2. **Ethereum Lists** https://github.com/ethereum-lists/tokens
   (If I'm not mistaken, mycrypto.com pull from here, for example.)
3. **MyEtherWallet Ethereum Lists** https://github.com/MyEtherWallet/ethereum-lists/tree/master/src/tokens/eth